# Rails: Self referential parent/child hierarchy without through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Event model with `parent_id` and `date` attributes:

Event.rb

```
has_many :children, :class_name => "Event"
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Event"
```

I have no issues calling `event.parent` or `event.children`. A child event never has a child itself.

I am trying to add a scope to this model so that I can return the child with the nearest future date for every parent. Something like:

```
scope :future, -> {
    where("date > ?", Date.today)
  }

scope :closest, -> {
    group('"parent_id"').having('date = MAX(date)')
 }

Event.future.closest ==> returns the closest child event from every parent
```

But the above `:closest` scope is returning more than one child per parent.

Comment: Do you need more than the immediate children (grandchildren, grand-grandchildren etc)?

Comment: No - a child cannot have a child.

Comment: The rails guides explain how to do this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins. There is also a railscast.

Comment: But what does the scope look like to get the nearest future child of each parent? I keep getting SQL errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring Rails for a moment, what you are doing in SQL is the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. Here are [lots of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/25534279). I would choose either `DISTINCT ON` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL`. Here is how it might look in Rails:

```
scope :closest, -> {
  select("DISTINCT ON (parent_id) events.*").
    order("parent_id, date ASC")
}
```

This will give you **the child objects**. (You probably also want a condition to exclude rows with no `parent_id`.) From your own solutions, it sounds like that's what you want. If instead you want **the parent objects**, with an optional attached child object, then use a lateral join. That is a little trickier to translate into ActiveRecord though. If it's acceptable to do it in two queries, this looks like it should work (sticking with `DISTINCT ON`):

```
has_one :closest_child, -> {
  select("DISTINCT ON (parent_id) events.*").
    order("parent_id, date ASC")
}, class_name: Event, foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

Then you can say `Event.includes(:closest_child)`. Again, you probably want to filter out all the non-parents though.

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer looks good, but I would refine it  the following way:

```
scope :closest, -> {
  where.not(parent_id: nil).group(:parent_id).minimum(:date)
}
```

And very important or else in production you would always get the deployment date as `Date.today` because it will only reload in development:

```
scope :future, -> {
  where("date > ?", Proc.new { Date.today })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
  scope :closest, -> {
    where(id: Event.group(:parent_id).minimum(:date).keys)
  }
```